# Showing Notification whenever new feed comes

Tags: android, xml-parsing, notifications

Hi guys just wanted to know how to show notification whenever new data comes in the online `xml` file.

For example, the **NDTV** news app: it gives notification whenever there is new news. How does it happen?

I am fetching data from an online `xml` file and showing it in a `ListView`, I need to show a real time notification whenever a new feed comes in the `xml` file. As soon as the `xml` is modified, the notification comes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want your app to be a battery drain, you are going to want to look into Google Cloud Messaging.  In a nutshell:

This is mor complicated, but it allows you to monitor the feed on on a WebServer or some other server and push updates to the device through Google. The app registers to be notified of these updates and when the Android OS gets notified of a message it sends a Broadcast intent that you will receive and can process by showing the notification.

If you are constantly polling, that would be a data/battery drain.